# How can I execute my tests in Debug in PyCharm using a Docker Python Interpreter?

Tags: python, debugging, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging

I configured PyCharm Python Interpreter as a remote Docker Python Interpreter:

[image]

I do not have any problem to run my tests using this configuration.

But when I try to run them in `Debug`, execution freeze to this `waiting for connection...` status:

[image]

So my questions are:

- What am I doing bad?
- How can I execute my tests in Debug in PyCharm using a Docker Python Interpreter ?

Comment: Please copy and paste the errors rather than uploading massive images which don't even fit on my 1080p monitor...

Comment: Done. Better like that I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to `pydevd` hardcoded host ip address in `PyCharm` sources (`10.0.0.2`).

So if you do not use `VirtualBox` to manage and run your `docker-machine`, you will not be able to easily launch your tests in debug.

It should be patched in `PyCharm 2016.3` for `docker interpreter` and in `PyCharm 2016.3.1` for `docker-compose interpreter`.

Awaiting this release, a workaround exist [here, on JetBrain website](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17447#comment=27-1390711&u=1477613091169).